# Jquery and ajax with json data parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

What is wrong with my code that i can not show anything in resultTXT

txtfld shows the array

```
[{
    "user_id": "2790",
    "freelancer_name": "",
    "order_id": "9121",
    "orderamount": "0.00",
    "payment_method": " ....... "
}]
```

I want the user ID to be in resultTXT

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        $.post('userfind.php', function(data) {
            $("#txtfld").val(data);

            var json = data,
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            alert(""+obj.user_id);
            $("#resultTXT").val(obj.user_id);
        },'json');
    }
};
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "userfind.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Please help me what should be changed.

Comment: Why do you have jQuery inside of a `ajaxRequest.open`?  Use either jQuery AJAX or vanilla JS AJAX, not both.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few things wrong with this.  First, why do you POST to `userfind.php` twice?  Why are you using vanilla JS AJAX and jQuery AJAX?  Just use one.

Second, the `,'json'` in `$.post` means jQuery will parse the JSON for you, you don't need `JSON.parse`.

Third, your JSON is an array (of objects), so you need to get the array element first, then the `user_id` property.

```
$.post('userfind.php', function(data) {
    $("#txtfld").val(data);  // data is an object,
                             // so this will just put [object Object] in the field,
                             // probably not what you want

    alert(data[0].user_id);  // data is an array of (one) object(s)
    $("#resultTXT").val(data[0].user_id);
},'json');
```

Comment: $("#txtfld").val(data);  shows the array i can see the array elements in the box.    and  alert(data[0].user_id);  // data is an array of (one) object(s)
    $("#resultTXT").val(data[0].user_id);
},'json');  doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because the json is an array so maybe try `obj[0].user_id`